# how to remove duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query to retrieve bunch of data but somehow it creates duplicate rows for certain records.I tried distinct but no use

What i am doing wrong here

```
  SELECT Distinct dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.ManagementZoneID, AssessmentEcosystemCreditID,dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.AssessmentVersionID , 
(COALESCE(dbo.tblManagementZone.SiteValueCurrentScore,0) 
-COALESCE(dbo.tblManagementZone.SiteValueFutureScore,0)) AS LossinSiteValueScore, 
5 AS SaveType, dbo.ufn_varbintohexstr(dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.RowTimestamp) AS RowTimestamp, 
dbo.tblVegetationZone.EECID, 
CASE WHEN dbo.tblVegetationZone.EECID > 0 THEN 3.0 
ELSE 1.0 
END AS EECOffSetMultiplier 
FROM dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblVegetationType 
ON dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.VegTypeID = dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblManagementZone 
ON dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.ManagementZoneID = dbo.tblManagementZone.ManagementZoneID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblVegetationZone 
ON dbo.tblVegetationZone.VegetationZoneID = dbo.tblManagementZone.VegetationZoneID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblAssessmentVersion AV ON 
AV.AssessmentVersionID = dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.AssessmentVersionID 
INNER JOIN tblAssessment TBA ON 
TBA.AssessmentID = AV.AssessmentID 
WHERE dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.AssessmentVersionID= @AssessmentVersionID
```

Comment: Are your joins using all the keys they should be?

Comment: If you use `SELECT DISTINCT` for a query then that query will not return duplicate rows.  Period.  You may have unwanted *partial* duplication, however, and/or you may have duplicate results from a non-`distinct` subquery or inline view.

Comment: yeah i provide all the keys but this happens only for few records not all

Comment: Comment out all the fields but one, then run the query.    Add back each field one at a time until the dupes occur.   Then you'll know which field is not actually duping.

Comment: thanks sparky, i am doing that already, hope will find out soon.

Comment: Is it possible that you do more `JOIN` than you need ? Usually my rule of thumb that works most of the time: "If I need the column in `SELECT` - it's a `JOIN`, otherwise: it's a `WHERE EXISTS` / `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you have duplicate rows in your central base table, `dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit`.  That should be easy to check, as you know which rows to look at.

More likely, you are obtaining multiple result rows corresponding to a few of the `dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit` rows because one of the tables you are joining to it has multiple matches for those rows.  That is, one of these columns contains at least one duplicated value:

```
dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID 
dbo.tblManagementZone.ManagementZoneID 
dbo.tblVegetationZone.VegetationZoneID
dbo.tblAssessmentVersion.AssessmentVersionID
tblAssessment.AssessmentID
```

The responsible column must not be subject to a single-column `UNIQUE` constraint, and must not be a single-column primary key for its table, so that may help narrow it down.  Note that the whole row does not need to be duplicated, only the ID.

Comment: you are right John, just found that ecosystem credit have duplicate based on managementzone id.

Comment: here is the thing i stuck now, if i use the following query "select  ManagementZoneID from tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit where AssessmentVersionID=2151" Rerturn 492 records. IF i use DISTINCT, it returns 14 record that is correct .Any idea how to remove the duplicate managementID from  ecosystemcredit table ?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. It is not inherently wrong for table `tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit` to have a many-to-one relationship with any of the other tables, in which case it can have duplicates of its foreign keys referencing those tables. It is all he other tables being joined to `tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit` that should not have duplicates. In my answer, the column names are qualified with the relevant table names.

Comment: I understand John,what you are trying to say but in my case i can clearly see ManagementzoneId is duplicated based on this record which is not right . For example if i removed all those duplicate records the query is going to return only 14 records.

Comment: Ok, as long as you're sure.  If different rows of `tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit` are all expected to have different `ManagementzoneId` values (or `NULL`), and you expect only 14 distinct `ManagementzoneId` values, then you must have a great number of incorrect rows in `tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit`.  They should be deleted, or possibly their `ManagementzoneId` values should be set `NULL`.  How to identify which rows should be affected, and whether to delete those row or nullify the column, both depend heavily on your data structure and your data.